# "Quotient" of category by arbitrary reflexive relation

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations, quotient-set

I went through the definition of the quotient of a category $\mathcal{C}$ by a congruence relation $\sim$ on the morphisms. I was very surprised to find that you can prove $\mathcal{C}/{\sim}$ is a category, with **only** the assumptions that $\sim$:

- is reflexive: $f \sim f$
- respects composition: if $f \sim f'$ and $g \sim g'$, then $fg \sim f'g'$.

In particular, nowhere did I need to assume that $\sim$ was symmetric or transitive.

This led me to thinking: what happens if you try to define the quotient by a "congruence" relation which is not necessarily symmetric or transitive? I figure that either:

- something goes wrong; or
- this turns out to be equivalent to e.g. the quotient by the symmetric transitive closure of $\sim$.

Comment: You are probably passing to the symmetric transitive closure implicitly somewhere. The fact that $=$ is an equivalence relation means that all quotients (of any kind of object) are implicitly quotients by equivalence relations.